# Choosing a particular route for a shuttle vehicle upon demand

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, graph-traversal

I'm trying to solve a problem where I have no idea what algorithm is to be used here to get the optimized answer. The problem is like this...

Consider there are 10 shuttle vehicles and 2 different routes in which they travel. Each vehicle has a seating capacity of 10 people. Normally each route will have 5 vehicles each (10 vehicles, 2 routes). I want to make the shuttle system smarter in a way that if Route 1 has more demand in users(shuttle running with full capacity) and Route 2 has minimal(where the number of passengers in each shuttle is less than 4), to tackle the demand needs, certain number of shuttle vehicles of Route 2 will come to Route 1. If the shuttle service in both routes are not in so demand(all running with less than 4 people), certain number of shuttle vehicles in both routes will stop running, and will be back running when the demand in users arises again.

Things to note : Distance is same in both routes, and the shuttles run free of charge for the passengers.

Which algorithm is best suited for these situations? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think some other factors need to be considered, to help narrow the focus because as-is there's no single algorithm. Eg, are there peak hours in which these routes or stops in the routes? What's the cost of traversing these routes or tasking a shuttle to its non-standard route and back again? You should name what exactly are you optimizing for, and the priority. Eg, you want to first keep the routes serviced, but not if it'd consume X% of a shuttle's fuel or make it miss peak hours of given parts of the route.

Comment: Yes there are peak hours where the entire cab fleet is running in full capacity, and non peak hours where there are only less than 4 people per cab. If cabs in a route are running in less capacity and the other route is still running on full capacity, a few cabs (max 2) will be taken to the other route to satisfy the needs. If both routes are having less passenger demand (all cabs with less than 4 people), a few cabs will be taken out of service and will be put back in service when the peak hour arrives.....Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: (1) Start with one shuttle on each route.  (2) If the load factor on a route exceeds a threshold, add another shuttle (if one is available).  (3) If the load factor on a route falls below a threshold, remove a shuttle (it's up to you if you want to run a single shuttle however low the load goes).  I don't think you need any more rules - except perhaps to take care of the case where there are no shuttles operating on a route in which case you've no idea what load factor there might be -- so on an empty route send a shuttle out occasionally to sample the demand.

Comment: Thank you very much! @High Performance Mark